# DbUpdateConcurrencyException when editing data that already exists even though I pass the variables needed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, concurrency

I'm getting the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` error even though I am passing the `OrderID` to the `OrderItem` form. It works on `Create` and `Delete`, but it keeps kicking me out for `Edit`. Can anyone please suggest a fix or let me know if I'm doing something wrong?

I get this `Concurrency Exception Error`:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException was
>   unhandled by user code   HResult=-2146233087   Message=Store update,
>   insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0).
>   Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.
>   See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on
>   understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
>   Source=EntityFramework   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
>          at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
>          at HealthHabitat.Controllers.OrderItemController.Edit(OrderItem orderItem) in c:\Users\Luffy\Desktop\HealthHabitat
>   V25\HealthHabitat\Controllers\OrderItemController.cs:line 97
>          at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Object tag)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   InnerException: System.Data.Entity.Core.OptimisticConcurrencyException
>          HResult=-2146233087
>          Message=Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or
>   deleted since entities were loaded. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on
>   understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
>          Source=EntityFramework
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ValidateRowsAffected(Int64
>   rowsAffected, UpdateCommand source)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.b__2(UpdateTranslator
>   ut)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T
>   noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35()
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions
>   options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__27()
>               at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions
>   options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions
>   options)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>          InnerException:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "OrderItemID,OrderID,ItemID,Quantity")] OrderItem orderItem)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(orderItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Order", new { id = orderItem.OrderID });
    }
    ViewBag.ItemID = new SelectList(db.Items, "ItemID", "Name", orderItem.ItemID);
    ViewBag.OrderID = new SelectList(db.Orders, "OrderID", "OrderID", orderItem.OrderID);
    return View(orderItem);
}
```

Edit View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { OrderID = Model.OrderID }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="panel panel-warning">
        <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
               @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrderID)

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ItemID, "Item Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownList("ItemID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ItemID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Order", new { id = Model.OrderID }, null)" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
                            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-warning"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            }
```

Model:

```
public class OrderItem
{

    public int OrderItemID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int ItemID { get; set; }

   [Range(1, 30, ErrorMessage = "{0} must be between {1} and {2}.")] // is this a row version?? I'm not sure, I'm kinda new to MVC
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }

}
```

GET Edit Method

```
// GET: OrderItem/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    OrderItem orderItem = db.OrderItems.Find(id);
    if (orderItem == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    ViewBag.ItemID = new SelectList(db.Items, "ItemID", "Name", orderItem.ItemID);
    ViewBag.OrderID = new SelectList(db.Orders, "OrderID", "OrderID", orderItem.OrderID);
    return View(orderItem);
}
```

Comment: Does OrderItem have a rowversion property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the RowVersion property on the view, and send it to the controller:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrderID)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RowVersion)
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "OrderItemID,OrderID,ItemID,Quantity,RowVersion")] OrderItem orderItem)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(orderItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Order", new { id = orderItem.OrderID });
    }
    ViewBag.ItemID = new SelectList(db.Items, "ItemID", "Name", orderItem.ItemID);
    ViewBag.OrderID = new SelectList(db.Orders, "OrderID", "OrderID", orderItem.OrderID);
    return View(orderItem);
}
```

Be aware that properties which were not modified on view will be empty. It is better to specify the modified properties.

```
//db.Entry(orderItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.Entry(orderItem).Property(i => i.Quantity).IsModified = true;
//...
```

**EDIT**

Just for testing purposes, instead of

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { OrderID = Model.OrderID }))
```

Try

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.HiddenFor(i => i.OrderID)
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Change your GET Action for:

```
// GET: OrderItem/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    OrderItem orderItem = db.OrderItems.Find(id);
    if (orderItem == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    ViewBag.DDL_ItemID = db.Items.Select(i => new SelectListItem { Text = i.Name, Value = i.ItemID.ToString() }).ToList();
    ViewBag.DDL_OrderID = db.Orders.Select(i => new SelectListItem { Text = i.OrderID.ToString(), Value = i.OrderID.ToString() }).ToList();
    return View(orderItem);
}
```

**Do not ever use a ViewBag property with the same name of a Model property**

Change the DropDownList in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(i => i.ItemID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DDL_ItemID, new { @class = "form-control"})
```

In the view, where did you put the OrderItemID? You have to put it there.

Comment: My apologies Fabio, my table does not have a row version. I misread my OrderItem table. Would I still need to change this line? `db.Entry(orderItem).Property(i => i.Quantity).IsModified = true;`

Comment: not necessary, that was just an advice because it seems that you are only changing this property... Please show the structure of the OrdemItem class

Comment: I've updated the question to include the class. Please see above.

Comment: Are you sure that all properties (OrderItemID, OrderID, ItemID, and Quantity) are being set in the action post?

Comment: It's actually only the `Quantity` that needs to be set, the `OrderIemID`, `OrderID` and `ItemID` need to stay the same. I also tried adding `db.Entry(orderItem).Property(i => i.Quantity).IsModified = true;` but it had a problem with `isModified`.

Comment: Yeah but, are the properties coming filled in the action? I mean, none of them can be null. Maybe, some of them are coming null

Comment: Yup, everything comes to the form.

Comment: Are you sure that the record you are trying to edit exists in database? Please, post the code of the get action Edit

Comment: See my edited answer. I believe I found the reason of your problem

Comment: Is there perhaps a bracket or something missing in those lines? It's giving me an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88896/discussion-between-fabio-luz-and-mustang00).