# How do I display a list of selected Orders and a list of unselected Orders on my edit Delivery screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need a solution on how to display all the `Orders` I have `selected` and all the `Orders` that haven't been `selected` on my `Edit Delivery` Screen for the current day. This is so that I can `deselect` a `Order` that I chose previously when I created the `Delivery` and then add another or add none.

So to give a bit of context, on my `Create Delivery`, I display a list of all the available `Orders` for that day and then select the `Orders` I want to add, and thus create the delivery.

However, now I want to go to my `Edit Delivery` screen to make changes to that `delivery`, which include `deselecting` and probably adding another `Order` or removing `Orders` that have been added. So I'm not sure how to tackle my GET and POST `Edit` methods and my `View` for `Edit Delivery`.

Can anyone advise me on a way forward? Would it be exactly the same as `Create Delivery`? Thanks in advance.

View Models:

```
public class OrderVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
public class DeliveryVM
{
  public int? ID { get; set; }
  public int DriverID { get; set; }
  public SelectList DriverList { get; set; }
  public List<OrderVM> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Edit Method:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Delivery delivery = db.Deliverys.Find(id);
    if (delivery == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewBag.DriverID = new SelectList(db.Drivers, "DriverID", "First_Name", delivery.DriverID);
    return View(delivery);
}

// POST: Delivery/Edit/5
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "DeliveryID,DriverID,Status,Comment,Dispatched_Date,Dispatched_Time,Delivered_Date,Delivered_Time,Delayed_Date,Delayed_Time")] Delivery delivery)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(delivery).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = delivery.DeliveryID });
    }
    ViewBag.DriverID = new SelectList(db.Drivers, "DriverID", "First_Name", delivery.DriverID);
    return View(delivery);
}
```

Controller Create Method:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  DeliveryVM model = new DeliveryVM()
  {
    DriverList = new SelectList(db.Drivers, "DriverID", "First_Name"),
    Orders = db.Orders.Where(o => o.Expected_Date == DateTime.Today).Select(o => new OrderVM()
    {
      ID = o.OrderID,
      Name = o.Hospital.Name,
    }).ToList()
  };
  return View(model);
}
public ActionResult Create(DeliveryVM model)
{
  Delivery delivery = new Delivery()
  {
    DriverID = model.DriverID,
    Dispatched_Date = DateTime.Now,
    Dispatched_Time = DateTime.Now,

  }
  db.Deliverys.Add(delivery);
  db.SaveChanges();
  // save the selected orders based on the ID of the Delivery object
  IEnumerable<int> selectedOrders = model.Orders.Where(o => o.IsSelected).Select(o => o.ID);
  foreach (int ID in selectedOrders)
  {
    Order order = db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderID == ID).FirstOrDefault();
    order.DeliveryID = delivery.DeliveryID;
    db.Entry.State = EntityState.Modified
  }
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

How the Create View looks:

```
@model DeliveryVM
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DriverID, Model.DriverList, "-Please select-")
  ....
  for(int i = 0; i < Model.Orders.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.HiddenForFor(m => m.Orders[i].ID)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Orders[i].IsSelected)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Orders[i].IsSelected, Model.Orders[i].Name)

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Edit()` method just needs to get all available orders in addition to your `Delivery` data model and then populate you view model with all orders and set the `IsSelected` property based on currently selected Orders. You already have a view model so do not use the data model. You have not shown you data models but I'm assuming `Delivery` contains a property `ICollection<Order> Orders`

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
  ....
  // Get your data model
  Delivery delivery = db.Deliverys.Find(id);
  ....
  // Get all available orders (see note below)
  var orders = db.Orders.Where(o => o.Expected_Date == DateTime.Today).Select(o => new OrderVM()
  {
    ID = o.OrderID,
    Name = o.Hospital.Name
  }).ToList();
  // Mark selected orders based on data model
  // Because you have not shown your data models, the following is a best guess
  IEnumerable<int> selectedOrders = delivery.Orders.Select(o => o.OrderID);
  foreach (var order in orders)
  {
    if (selectedOrders.Contains(order.ID))
    {
      order.IsSelected = true;
    }
  }
  // Initialize the view model
  DeliveryVM model = new DeliveryVM()
  {
    ID = delivery.DeliveryID,
    DriverID = delivery.DriverID,
    Orders = orders,
    DriverList = new SelectList(db.Drivers, "DriverID", "First_Name")
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

Side note: Using `.Where(o => o.Expected_Date == DateTime.Today)` will probably not be correct unless your editing the `Delivery` on the same day you created it. Your data model will need to include a `DateTime` property so you can select the applicable orders. For example it might be something like `.Where(o => o.Expected_Date == delivery.DeliveryDate)`

You `Edit` view will be the same as your `Create` and will now show the all orders, and those that have been previous selected will be checked in the view.

Finally, change your POST method to

```
HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(DeliveryVM model)
{
  // similar to your Create() method, except that you are saving an existing 
  // Delivery rather than adding one (and you may not need to save it unless
  // the Driver has changed) and updating the collection of Orders based on
  // the IsSelected property
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks again Stephen. I have posted another question regarding Order Items here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32405011/dbupdateconcurrencyexception-when-editing-data-that-already-exists-even-though-i?noredirect=1#comment52682777_32405011 - its a dbupdateconcurrencyexception error? I don't know if you have any experience with that, but maybe you can see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You noted in the comment to the question that the table includes a field for version which means you need to include and input for that in your form, but the correct approach is use a view model, then get the data model from the database in the POST method and update data model based on the view model properties (otherwise you open yourself to over-posting attacks from malicious users)

Comment: Hi Stephen, your method works perfectly. There's just one issue, everytime I try to save after editing a value on the delivery I get a DbUpdateException Error. Any idea why?

Comment: You would need to provide more details on the error and where its occurring (I assume its on `db.Entry(delivery).State = EntityState.Modified;`)? Best you ask a new question with the details and I'll have a look

Comment: Its actually on the db.SaveChanges, but let me post a new question.

Comment: OK, Include the 2 data models, the 2 view models and the POST method for `Edit`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32412715/dbupdateexception-unhandled-when-trying-to-save-delivery-and-order-after-editing - I also have the same problem with Edit Order. Except I don't use ViewModels for  Order, just for Delivery. But I'll update the question with all the models.