# DbUpdateException unhandled when trying to save in POST method of Delivery and Order after editing respectively

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unhandled-exception

I seem to be getting `DbUpdateException` error on `db.SaveChanges()` after I edit my `Delivery` or `Order`. I'm not sure why, it works fine for `Create` and `Delete`.

Am I missing something somewhere? The GET `Edit` methods work fine for both.

I get this `exception` error:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException was unhandled by
>   user code   HResult=-2146233087   Message=An error occurred while
>   updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>   Source=EntityFramework   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
>          at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
>          at HealthHabitat.Controllers.DeliveryController.Edit(DeliveryVM model) in c:\Users\Luffy\Desktop\HealthHabitat
>   V25\HealthHabitat\Controllers\DeliveryController.cs:line 172
>          at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Object tag)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   InnerException: System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException
>          HResult=-2146233087
>          Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>          Source=EntityFramework
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.b__2(UpdateTranslator
>   ut)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T
>   noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35()
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions
>   options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__27()
>               at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions
>   options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions
>   options)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>          InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>               HResult=-2146232060
>               Message=The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement
>   has been terminated.
>               Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
>               ErrorCode=-2146232060
>               Class=16
>               LineNumber=1
>               Number=242
>               Procedure=""
>               Server=(LocalDb)\v11.0
>               State=3
>               StackTrace:
>                    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>                    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>                    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>                    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>                    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>                    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>                    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>                    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds)
>                    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)
>                    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)
>                    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)
>                    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>                    at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>                    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.b__c(DbCommand
>   t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
>                    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget
>   target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>                    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand
>   command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>                    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>                    at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>                    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2
>   identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
>                    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
>               InnerException:

**Order Controller POST:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "OrderID,HospitalID,StaffID,Date,Time,Expected_Date")] Order order)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = order.OrderID });
    }
    //ViewBag.DeliveryID = new SelectList(db.Deliverys, "DeliveryID", "DeliveryID", order.DeliveryID);
    ViewBag.HospitalID = new SelectList(db.Hospitals, "HospitalID", "Name", order.HospitalID);
    ViewBag.StaffID = new SelectList(db.Staffs, "StaffID", "First_Name", order.StaffID);
    return View(order);
}
```

**Delivery Controller POST:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(DeliveryVM model)
{
    Delivery delivery = new Delivery()
    {
        DriverID = model.DriverID,

    };
    db.Deliverys.Add(delivery);
    db.SaveChanges();
    // save the selected orders based on the ID of the Delivery object
    IEnumerable<int> selectedOrders = model.Orders.Where(o => o.IsSelected).Select(o => o.ID);
    foreach (int ID in selectedOrders)
    {
        Order order = db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderID == ID).FirstOrDefault();
        order.DeliveryID = delivery.DeliveryID;
        db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = delivery.DeliveryID });
```

**Order Model:**

```
public int OrderID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Hospital")]
    public int HospitalID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Staff")]
    public int StaffID { get; set; }
    public int? DeliveryID { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Expected_Date { get; set; }
    public virtual Hospital Hospital { get; set; }
    public virtual Staff Staff { get; set; }
    public virtual Delivery Delivery { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
```

**Delivery Model:**

```
public enum Status
{
   Dispatched, Delayed, Delivered
}
public class Delivery
{

    public int DeliveryID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Driver")]
    public int DriverID { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Date Dispatched")]
    public DateTime Dispatched_Date { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Time Dispatched")]
    public DateTime Dispatched_Time { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Date Delivered")]
    public DateTime? Delivered_Date { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Time Delivered")]
    public DateTime? Delivered_Time { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Date Delayed")]
    public DateTime? Delayed_Date { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Time Delayed")]
    public DateTime? Delayed_Time { get; set; }



    public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModels:**

```
    public enum Status
    {
        Dispatched, Delayed, Delivered
    }
    public class DeliveryVM
    {
        public int? ID { get; set; }
        public int DriverID { get; set; }

        public Status Status { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
        public string Comment { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Date Dispatched")]
        public DateTime Dispatched_Date { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Time Dispatched")]
        public DateTime Dispatched_Time { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Date Delivered")]
        public DateTime? Delivered_Date { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Time Delivered")]
        public DateTime? Delivered_Time { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Date Delayed")]
        public DateTime? Delayed_Date { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Time Delayed")]
        public DateTime? Delayed_Time { get; set; }
        public SelectList DriverList { get; set; }
        public List<OrderVM> Orders { get; set; }
    }

public class OrderVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address_1 { get; set; }
    public string Address_2 { get; set; }
    public string Address_3 { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int DeliveryID { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }


}
```

**PLEASE NOTE:** I didn't use `ViewModels` for `Edit Order`, only for `Edit Delivery`.

Comment: What's the inner exception?

Comment: As @StephenMuecke said the error with datetime. Also check `StaffID` field for `Order`. Dropdown list for it does not have items: ` @Html.DropDownList("StaffID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "true" })`

Comment: @Artyom, I want it to take all the values that was added to the `Order` upon creating, if that makes sense. The only value that should be changeable is the `expected_date`. However, I still want it to display those details, so that's why I've included them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important part of the error is

> Message=The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value`.

Both `Delivery` and `Order` have a number of `DateTime` fields and at least one of them is not being set when you save so their values are `01/01/0001` (i.e. `DateTime.MinValue`), but your database table field is DATETIME which only has a year range of `1753-9999`. To prevent the error, you can change the sql type to `DATETIME2` which matches the c# `DateTime` range.

However, I suspect the real issue is that you really should be setting the `DateTime` property. Your `Edit()` POST method has

```
Delivery delivery = new Delivery()
{
    DriverID = model.DriverID,
};
db.Deliverys.Add(delivery);
```

however an `Edit()` method suggests your editing and existing object, so it should be

```
// Get the data model based on the ID of the view model
Delivery delivery = db.Delivery.Find(model.ID);
// Map the view model properties to the data model
delivery.DriverID = model.DriverID;
// Mark as modified and save
db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: The thing is that, I don't want the `date` or `time` to change, I want it to take the value that it was already given when creating. So for example, on `Delivery`, `dispatched_date` and `dispatched_time` shouldn't change. The only thing that will change is the `status`, but if the `status` changes to `Delivered`or `Delayed`, then I'll be saving the current date and time for the fields relating to that `status`. Ditto for `Order`, the only `date` that I should change on `Order` is the `expected_date`

Comment: No you wont. By using `Delivery delivery = db.Delivery.Find(model.ID);` your getting the original item from the data base and then you only update the properties you want. The other properties that you don't explicitly set will just remain the same

Comment: This line `Delivery delivery = db.Delivery.Find(model.ID);` is in my GET method, so that's fine. I took away `Delivery delivery = new Delivery` and I just put `delivery.DriverID = model.DriverID;` along with the other values that might change. These two lines `db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;`
`db.SaveChanges();` are in a `foreach` like in my question above, but I'm getting errors. :(

Comment: No I mean you also need `Delivery delivery = db.Delivery.Find(model.ID);` in the POST method (the last code snippet in my answer is what you need in the POST method). In you existing code block you adding a new `Delivery` but both `Dispatched_Date` and `Dispatched_Time` are `01/01/0001` which throws the error.

Comment: But it does seem rather strange that you have both a `Dispatched_Date` and `Dispatched_Time` property - Is there any special reason why its not just one property?

Comment: Alright, so to confirm, I just have to replace my code with your structure in the snippet, and just map the other properties. Then I should be good to go?

Comment: We wanted to record date and time separately, but I guess it is redundant.  You think it will make it less complicated if it were in one property?

Comment: Yes, should be fine - just get the original and update only those properties your want (e.g., the Driver and/or the Status). And to check, put a breakpoint on `db.SaveChanges();` and then inspect all the values in `delivery` to see that it contains the original dates

Comment: Alright, I've made the changes. It just has a problem with `db.Delivery.Find(model.ID);` and  `db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;` It states that it can't find `Delivery` and `order`.

Comment: Are you sure `model.ID` contains the correct value (you have posted so much code here its difficult to scroll though it all - you really need to start debugging your code and checking the values as you step through it).

Comment: I fixed it, Turns out that I commented out some code that I needed! For `Edit`of `Order`, would I need to change to DateTime2 in the SQL?

Comment: Only if you intend to store `DateTime` values that are outside the range of years 1753 to 9999 (so I assume probably not)

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why it doesn't save. I used the default code for that the controller gave me. I don't want to change the `date` or `time` there either, I just want to change `expected_date` for the Order.

Comment: Sorry, but which method are you now referring to? The POST method in the OrderController or in the DeliveryController

Comment: The Order Controller method. I think the issue was that it wasn't taking the `StaffID` and `HospitalID` from the form since I disabled the boxes. What I did was that I added the `IDs` to form using a HiddenFor attribute and now it works fine. Thanks.